# udevadm get ID_SERIAL_SHORT only

Tags: linux

I have command `udevadm info --query=all -n /dev/sda`
it prints all information but I just need to print value of ID_SERIAL_SHORT.
The best is one-liner for this.

Any idea how to get just ID_SERIAL_SHORT only?

Answer (score 1):

I found solution recently, this did it:

```
udevadm info --query=property --name=/dev/sda | grep ID_SERIAL_SHORT
```

Answer (score 0):

Following command can be used to print `ID_SERIAL_SHORT`

`lsblk --nodeps -o serial`

Comment: You could improve your answer by explaining the options and citing a refetence